# Show Downthemall addon download manager for firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I was quite long searching for a good GUI download manager for ubuntu. I used Flareget, uget etc. but then I came upon an add-on for firefox named as Downthemall. You can find it [here](http://www.downthemall.net). It is best but I have one problem. When power cuts off, computer powers off. When I restart computer and restart mozilla firefox, I am unable to find the downthemall download manager window. I start another download and thus window pops up. Any way to make the download manager window automatically visible when download is in progress. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try clicking on the Open Menu button in the top bar:

[image]

Then, click on the Customize button:

[image]

You should see the DownThemAll Download Manager somewhere there. Simply drag and drop the icon to your task bar or into the Menu! Then, you can just click that button and you're good to go!

I don't use DownThemAll myself, so I don't have it installed and can't be *entirely* certain that will fix your issue, but it *should*.

Comment: Are you sure You haven't used and you answered this!! I mean really, really and really this works. Did you say you don't use downthemall, then what do you use. Please share with us. Thanks alot.

Comment: @RehanUllah You were able to bring up the download manager again? Awesome :D Glad to help. As for what I use, well, I just use the default download manager - fairly boring, but it works for what I need.

Comment: Thank you for support. You a pro computer user using default manager? Amazing!

Comment: @RehanUllah np ;)

Answer (score 1):

If found a command that works for Linux and OSX, just run on terminal:

```
firefox -no-remote -chrome chrome://dta/content/dta/manager.xul
```

Then you can create a shortcut and customize the icon, etc.